# Cannot define Class const as a binary string - phpserial, Laravel, PHP

Tags: php, constants

I am using phpserial in a Laravel home project to output light settings to a DMX light controller via a serial USB port. This works fine if I declare a protected string, but when I try to set a const in the class this does not work.

How do I create a const which consists of 3 binary bytes (1,0,1) ?

Code snippet:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use PhpSerial;

class SerialCommsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The Serial Interface
     */
    protected $serial;
    CONST INITLIGHTS = chr(1) . chr(0) . chr(1); // THIS FAILS BUT CONST MUST BE DECLARED AT TOP SCOPE IN CLASS
    protected $initLights;
    /**
     * Create a new serial interface
     *

     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->serial = new PhpSerial();
        //Get environmental config or if not available, use the default (second parameter_
        $this->serial->deviceSet(env('SERIAL_DEVICE','USB0'));
        $this->serial->confBaudRate(env('SERIAL_BAUD_RATE','9600'));
        $this->serial->confParity(env('SERIAL_PARITY','none'));
        $this->serial->confCharacterLength(env('SERIAL_CHARACTER_LENGTH',8));
        $this->serial->confStopBits(env('SERIAL_STOP_BITS',1));
        $this->serial->confFlowControl(env('SERIAL_FLOW_CONTROL','none'));
        if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
            // So now we need to open it
            $this->serial->deviceOpen();
            $this->initLights = chr(1) . chr(0) . chr(1); //THIS WORKS FINE, BUT AS THE INIT STRING IS A CONSTANT...
```

Comment: `CONST INITLIGHTS = "\x00\x01\x00"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) state that a class constant must be `a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, or a function call.`; and while PHP 5.6 added support for basic expressions in a constant definition, it still doesn't support calls to functions.

However, you can express that character sequence without needing to call `chr()` to do so

```
CONST INITLIGHTS = "\x00\x01\x00";
```

so no use of variables, properties, function calls or even expressions, simply a string definition